# how to increase the precision and recall value

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

hi am trying to create a staff promotion aloghritim which will have a high recall and precision value,trying to fit my model but get this error
pls help below is my collab link to my works so far
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ugKUswSjwnrfActsu2E-1gSg94ylwUJK

```
import catboost as ctb
from sklearn import metrics 
    # fit a CART model to the data
parameters = {'depth'         : [6,8,10],
                  'learning_rate' : [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
                  'iterations'    : [30, 50, 100]
                 }
model = ctb.CatBoostClassifier(silent=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(); print(model)


     # make predictions
expected_y  = y_train
predicted_y = model.predict(X_test)

    # summarize the fit of the model
print(); print(metrics.classification_report(expected_y, predicted_y))
print(); print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected_y, predicted_y))
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-abdfdbe585e3> in <module>()
     16 
     17     # summarize the fit of the model
---> 18 print(); print(metrics.classification_report(expected_y, predicted_y))
     19 print(); print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected_y, predicted_y))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    203     if len(uniques) > 1:
    204         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 205                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [30649, 7663]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: done pls help edited

Answer (score 1):

From your abbreviations, I think it should be

```
expected_y = y_test
```

instead of

```
expected_y  = y_train
```